# How to avoid idle automatic logout inside my web.config

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, iis-7.5, form-authentication

I am working on an asp.net mvc web application, that uses form authentication which talks directly to our active directory through LDap. On the staging server the user will stay logged-in unless he manually logs out. The problem is when I deploy the application on the live server using IIS 7 the user will be logged out after around 30 minutes if he did not work on the application. I thought the problem was related to the IIS idle time out, but when I checked the settings on the staging IIS I found the following:

[image]

but on staging no automatic logout will occur, so it seems the Idle timeout setting is meaningless in my situation.  I want to be able to override any undesired setting inside the IIS that might be different on different servers. So my question is how can I specify inside my web.config to not logout the user?

Bearing in mind that on both the live and staging server I have the following setting inside the web.config:

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
```

Comment: Check your session timeout value. Ultimately, forms auth depends on the session, so if the session times out, it doesn't matter what value you had set for forms auth. However, having a never expiring session is not a great idea either. If you want to allow a user to stay logged in. Implement a "Remember me" feature, which is typically cookie-backed, but bear in mind that even there, it's not forever and usually expires after two weeks if the user has not returned.

Comment: @ChrisPratt i have set a remember me check box with the following code;- "FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);". But even selecting a remember me will not solve the problem,,seems there is something somewhere causing the session to expire if the user is idle .... so i need to override this ..